# What is the name of the last song in the staff credits at the end of episode 25?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

Well, I know it's called *Great Escape* and it's the ending song of the 2nd cour of Shingeki no Kyojin. However, the one played at the end of episode 25 was an edited version.

Where can I find this edited version of the song?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! It's track #10 on cinema staff's latest album, [Drums,Bass,2(to)Guitars](http://www.amazon.co.jp/Drums-Bass-2-Guitars-%E9%80%9A%E5%B8%B8%E7%9B%A4/dp/B00I4FM6HI) (released 2 Apr 2014). I haven't listened to it myself (the sample is too short to be able to tell the difference between the regular version and the ep25 version), but according to the product description, this is what you're looking for:

> 「great escape」はTVアニメ「進撃の巨人」の最終回のみで使用された特別バージョンで収録。
>
> This album includes the special version of "great escape" that was used only in the last episode of the TV anime "Shingeki no Kyojin".

Comment: How can confirm it if I can't listen to it in there?

Comment: @HashiramaSenju Buy the album? Not ideal, I'll grant, and it would've been nice if that song was available as a single, but dem's the breaks.

Comment: Oh, this might be it, actually - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7cnKZb9AI8